# Arrays of function pointers as members of classes

Tags: c++

Can I have, as a private member of a class, an array of function pointers?  Something like,

```
class MyClass {
public: //public stuff

private:
void (*specficFunctions[16]) (void);
}
```

I specifically don't want to use functors or functionoids.

Comment: Have you actually tried it and if so what were your errors? [because it's perfectly legal to `have, as a private member of a class, an array of function pointers`]

Comment: I suppose you do know that _member_ function pointers differ from pointers to _non-member_ functions? (And, if you need an array of member function pointers, reconsider your design. Virtual functions are implemented this way. No need to re-implement them.)

Comment: I haven't yet.  I'm still roughing it in.  This is the kind of thing, for me, that would be hard to fix if I screwed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though you usually want to use a typedef to keep the syntax a bit more manageable:

```
class MyClass { 
    typedef void (*fptr)(void);

    fptr SpecificFunctions[16];
};
```

Note, however, that these are pointers to *global* functions, *not* member functions.

Comment: Typedefs are fine, and I will use them.  The thing I am [still] working on suffers from brittleness for a couple of reasons.  I'm trying to isolate that brittleness into a single unit, while keeping it functional.  Then I'm going to work off the problems.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about function pointers. The declaration syntax may be confusing (which can be mitigated with typedefs) but they're not really different from any other pointer. If you can make an array of pointers, you can make an array of function pointers. There's also nothing special about a private member of a class compared with any other type of variable. If you can make an array, you can make an array a private member of a class.

Comment: I realized after the fact that the 'private' part was not an important part of it.  As I recall, member functions compile with an implicit reference to 'this' object.  I didn't know how that might affect function-pointers-as-members [rather than the more common pointers-to-member-functions].

Comment: @David: The `this` is only implicit to member _functions_, not to _data_ members.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  (You can always answer this kind of question by trying to compile such code.)

Comment: Compilation is not a good test of whether something is allowed in general.  You may be hitting an odd compiler extension, or one of the last few incompatibilities it has with the Standard.